# ¿Como se cambia la ip a la que se enlaza un contenedor docker?

Tags: linux, docker

Cree un contenedor docker con una base de datos en un equipo con la IP (host) 10.1.1.100, el contenedor tiene una aplicación web así que se le direcciona el puerto 80 del contenedor al puerto 80 de la ip.

```
docker run --name contenedor -d -p 10.1.1.100:80:80 something/something
```

Todo funcionó correctamente hasta que se dió la necesidad de cambiar la IP del host.
Al momento de cambiar la IP (a 10.1.1.200) y arrancar el contenedor `docker start contenedor` me da un error:

> Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   conectivity on endpoint...: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp
>   10.1.1.100:80: bind: cannot assign requested address.
>   Error: failed to start containers: contenedor

¿Que hay que hacer para levantar este contenedor? No quiero volver a generarlo de cero porque ya tiene mucha información en su base de datos.
Docker Version 1.13.1 CentOS 7 64bits

Antemano gracias.

Comment: no se mucho de docker pero esta claro que el port 80 esta ya ocupado... y leyendo un poco la documentación debes usar (creo) un [clean-up --rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez creado un contenedor con unos parámetros ya no se pueden modificar. Podrías exportar el contenedor ("docker save") y levantarlo de nuevo como otro diferente ("docker load") con otros parámetros.

Entonces ya si es una base de datos monta un volúmen con "docker volume" para que la próxima vez puedas desechar el contenedor pero conservar la información de la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un `commit` del contenedor y crear una nueva imagen.

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
EJ: docker commit -m "move container to my new host" something/something:v2
```

Una vez hecho esto vuelves a ejecutar el contenedor con la nueva version

```
docker run --name contenedor -d -p 10.1.1.200:80:80 something/something:v2
```

Por otro lado si es una **BBDD** tal vez sería mejor que compartieras el volumen con la **opción -v** para que tus datos no dependan de la imagen del contenedor. Una vez hecho el `commit` puedes hacer un volumen que comparta tu carpeta de la **bbdd**.

`docker run --name contenedor -d -p 10.1.1.200:80:80 -v bbdd-data:/path-datos-del-contenedor something/something:v2`

Esto creará un nuevo volumen en tu `host` llamado `bbdd-data` y copiara los datos de la carpeta `/path-datos-del-contenedor`